# group and get value in table

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have 2 tables

**Users**

```
----------------
user_id | name
----------------
   33   | jon
   35   | igor 
   40   | mark
```

**event**

```
-----------------------------------
event_id | user_id | lavel | value
-----------------------------------
    1    |    33   | status|   1
    2    |    33   | ins   |   alfa
    3    |    33   | time  |   14:30
    4    |    35   | status|   0
    5    |    35   | ins   |   beta
    6    |    35   | time  |   14:51
    7    |    40   | ins   |   beta
```

**intended Query Result**

```
------------------------
user_id | name | status
------------------------
   33   | jon  |   1
   35   | igor |   0
   40   | mark |
```

I want the users in the table and their status.

The status is a administration field. Can not be.

Can anyone help with the query?

Comment: Two events deliberately share the same id?

Comment: nothing i think !! kkk

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, 
CASE WHEN e.value IS NULL THEN '' ELSE e.value AS status
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN event e ON e.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE e.lavel = 'status'
```

If you can, it seems like it would be a much more manageable table if your column headers were like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
event_id | user_id | status | ins | time
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm trying queries like that, adding group by. Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated for the new use case you've added, assuming there will be only one status entry per person

Comment: I tried this query: 
`SELECT u.user_id, u.name, 
CASE e.lavel WHEN 'status' THEN e.value ELSE e.value END AS status
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN event e ON e.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY e.user_id`

But I only get "NULL"

Comment: Both sides of your `CASE` statement return `e.value`, that seems pointless.

Comment: You can't group by user unless there will be multiple rows of the same user with the same status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax :

```
    select 
    user.id,
    user.name,
    event.value 
    from user inner join event 
    on user.id=ever.user_id 
   WHERE event.lavel = 'status';
```